# How do I troubleshoot a system freeze (100% unresponsive)?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, freeze

I have xrdp set up and I frequently remote into my laptop running Ubuntu from my Windows desktop. Last night I remoted normally and instead of logging out, I shutdown the computer remotely. It prompted me with a message along the lines of "are you sure you want shutdown? There are other users logged in". I chose yes and it shutdown properly. I've done this before so I would like to think this is insignificant.

Today, I open up my laptop and start brave browser. After a couple of minutes of normal and flawless use, my system completely freezes. Completely unresponsive. Nothing works. Keyboard, mouse, etc. does not work. Clock doesn't move. Everything.

Alt+SysRq+REISUB won't even work. I even wait a couple seconds between each new command.

When I have my laptop on and I'm not using brave browser, everything works fine. I can run commands in terminal, connect to internet, control audio, etc. I've had it sitting idle for 10+ minutes and it hasn't froze and is still responsive so hopefully I can pinpoint the issue on the browser.

I haven't tried another browser to see if the same thing happens because I've force shutdown my laptop around 4 times now and I would really prefer not to have to do that again.

**I can access /var/log/syslog but I have no idea what I'm looking for. How do I troubleshoot this?**

**UPDATE 1:** It's not brave. I opened vscode and discord and they also make it freeze. Another thing to note is that immediately after it freezes, the fan turns on and the laptop starts getting warmer like it's using a lot of power to process something. Maybe I should leave it alone for a bit?

**UPDATE 2:** Here's the syslog that I shortened to what I believe is the significant part: https://pastebin.com/hNQ555sB

Also, here are some people that have the same issue:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958443
- https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net&q=subject:%22%5C%5BKernel%5C-packages%5C%5D+%5C%5BBug+1958443%5C%5D+Re%5C%3A+Ubuntu+randomly+freezes+with%095.13.0%5C-27+%5C%5Brtw_8821ce+0000%5C%3A01%5C%3A00.0%5C%3A+pci+bus+timeout%2C%09check+dma+status%5C%5D%22&o=newest

System Info:

HP Laptop 15t-dy200

Processor: Intel Core i7-1165G7

Graphics: Intel Iris xe

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Kernel 5.13.0-27

256 gb SSD

16gb RAM

---

There's a bug in Kernel 5.13.0-27 of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (refer to my links below update 2). I downgraded to 5.11.0-46 and everything works fine now.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include some of the logs from around the time your system froze? This may make it easier to identify what the problem is 

Comment: @matigo Done! Looks like I need to revert back to kernel 5.11 if that's possible until the bug is fixed? https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg470120.html